# Can non-blocking system calls be interrupted?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, signals, system-calls

I am reading [The Linux Programming Interface](http://man7.org/tlpi/) which describes (in section 21.5) how a blocking system call can be interrupted by a signal. This seems to imply that a non-blocking system call cannot be interrupted. Is this true?

Comment: As signals are asynchronous the SIGINT may be interrupting your program outside of any system calls. I am wondering whether a program can be interrupted after a non-blocking system call is called but before it returns.

Comment: I think generically any system call can be interrupted by a signal. "Non-blocking" only means that making the system call won't deschedule your process, but the system call still has to *run*, and during that time a signal may arrive.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense to me. Perhaps the example mentioned blocking system calls specifically just because they are much more likely to get interrupted, but the book is very precise with how it describes everything so I have a feeling it really is only specific to blocking system calls, but I have no evidence for that

Comment: I guess you could test this by calling alarm() to schedule a signal and then calling some non-blocking call in a tight loop and examining the stack content in the signal handler, and checking the return value from the system call

Answer (score 0):

The question is mostly meaningless because there is little or no (no portable) observable difference between a signal interrupting the syscall and one interrupting userspace one cycle before or after the syscall.

Comment: It isn't meaningless when programming; if a non-blocking syscall can be interrupted, a programmer must check for error code EINTR by default and in which case the syscall will likely need to be restarted (normal and expected behaviour). If a non-blocking syscall cannot be interrupted then this check isn't necessary and the failed syscall is likely to be fatal - assuming all non-blocking syscalls cannot be interrupted may result in unnecessary fatal errors

Comment: Oh, `EINTR`. Don't enable it at all if your intent is not to treat interruption as an actual error. And that's a bogus intent since it has inherent race conditions. So just don't enable it at all.

Comment: I was asking the question more from a theoretical perspective to understand the Linux kernel a bit better, but yeah that's a possible workaround

Comment: @dippynark: On error handling: If the failure of any function call impacts the program's behaviour in an unwanted way, handle each error code it is documented to set.

Comment: @alk I know how to handle/find out about syscall errors, I'm asking the question to learn more about how to kernel works - the potentially returned errors isn't the only thing you need to think about either, if you're using signals handlers and you don't know when your program can be interrupted, reentrancy can cause issues